# Laravel 5.7 - Ckeditor stopped showing after using command 'php artisan make:auth'

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, ckeditor, laravel-artisan

Before using the command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

the ckeditor, taken from the website https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor

was working fine.

After using the command, the ckeditor code has dissapeared in the file app.blade.php. In this case, the code

```
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' );
</script>
```

was put again in the app.blade.php and the following commands in the terminal were used once more:

```
composer require unisharp/laravel-ckeditor
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=ckeditor
```

Also,in the config/app.php in the addservice provider is still the:

```
Unisharp\Ckeditor\ServiceProvider::class,
```

I am doing tutorial from traversy media channel on the youtube, which link is the following [laravel from scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORus3-By4lk&list=PLillGF-RfqbYhQsN5WMXy6VsDMKGadrJ-&index=9)

My question is, what else I must write down in the Laravel, that the CKeditor will be visible.

Comment: any reason you are using 5.7 that hasn't been released yet?

Comment: as I know, it is already on its website   https://laravel.com/docs/5.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You done everything right, 
but after running this command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

The newly created app.blade.php contain "defer" in the line

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

So remove the "defer", so it would be like

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

and this will work.

You can also move it to just before the `</body>` tag.